# I want to get "0.8" from my string using PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I have a string

```
$string = "2.5 lakh videos views 0.8";
```

Now I want to get "0.8" from above string using PHP.

Comment: can you show your total code..?

Comment: THere are a number of ways of doing that. What have you tried

Comment: Do you want to simply get the last 3 charakters or can the number change?

Comment: Hello Sir, As I am getting different strings from table like, $string1 = "66.33 lakh videos views 10.12";  $string2 = "200 lakh videos views 0.60";  $string3 = "14 lakh videos views 22.7"; ...etc. but I want to get only last numbers from string using PHP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the last 3 characters:

```
$string = "2.5 lakh videos views 0.8";
$valSubstr = substr($string, -3);
echo $valSubstr;
```

To get the last "part" of the sentence. (this way you don't have to care about the count of characters in your number)

```
$string = "2.5 lakh videos views 0.8";
$partsString = explode(' ', $string);
$valExplode = $partsString[count($partsString) - 1];
echo $valExplode;
```

Both methods are bad, because you can only hope your data is in the format you expect it to be. But if your data is always in the format you showed, it would work. You can add a regex to check for unwanted characters like a trailing ".".

Comment: Hello Sir, As I am getting different strings from table like, $string1 = "kapil sharma videos views 100.12"; $string2 = "200 lakh Indian Idol videos views for 0.60"; $string3 = "Sab Ki Holi videos views 22.7"; ...etc. but every string is ending with some number like 100.12, 0.60, 22.7 etc. and I want to get those number only.

Comment: The second snippet will work for those numbers. They only have to be at the end of the string.

Answer (score 0):

You can use php function `substr()` like this `substr($string,-3);`.